# Simplehtmldom repeats the extracted field previously

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I would like to extract the list from [this page](https://www.exophase.com/game/nioh-ps4/trophies), but every time he also repeats the previous field, creating a kind of "pyramid".
Example:

> You Are Nioh Obtained all
>   trophies.
>
> You Are Nioh A Long Journey Begins Obtained all trophies.Completed
>   "The Man with the Guardian
>
> You Are Nioh A Long Journey Begins They Call Him Anjin Obtained all
>   trophies.Completed "The Man with the Guardian Spirit".Completed "Deep
>   in the

This is my code, where am I wrong? I would need to create the kind of query so that I can execute in the database.

```
foreach ($html->find('li.award') as $infop) {
  $escapedHtmlChars .= htmlspecialchars($infop);
  $title  .= $infop->find('div.trophy-title', 0)->plaintext;
  echo $title;
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. This means getting rid of custom functions like `file_get_html()`, and including data directly instead of from a URL.

Comment: Also, do you understand what the `.=` operator does?

Comment: It was just the operator to cause this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `.=` operator, you are appending to your string with each iteration of the loop. Just use a plain `=` operator instead!